# How to increase cascade-lake vCPU speed in GCP (3.1 to 3.8 GHz)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have taken GCP C2 (compute optimized) type ubuntu machine, with 4vcpu, 16-G ram, 200G ssd, which houses intel cascade lake cpu. The  google docs indicate its speed as 3.8Ghz, however the machine indicate cpu speed as 3.1 Ghz.

Is there something we are supposed to do to increase the cpu speed, or ask google anything?

Comment: Have you checked if your region is the one with the available C2 3.8 GHz CPUs? Because I didn't see any limit in the quotas about CPUs speed but it can be region-dependent.
Check for example the list here https://kinsta.com/blog/boosting-wordpress-performance/#available-regions-for-c2-instances

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms#intel_cpu_processors) doc, C2's base clock frequency is 3.1, while All-core turbo frequency is 3.8.

Base clock frequency: A lower bound on CPU frequency, and the frequency at which the time stamp counter (TSC) increments.
**All-core turbo frequency**: The frequency at which each CPU typically runs when all cores in the socket are not idle at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Promoted frequency is single-core turbo frequency and the CPU goes to turbo mode on load for a short period. Turbo frequency is different if a single CPU core is in Turbo Mode or all cores are in Turbo Mode. The advertised turbo frequency is if the CPU is only running a single core. So most of the time, the CPU runs on default frequency and sometimes in all-core turbo frequency. 3.8 or 3.9 GHz are the marketing values, in reality, you get a 3.1 GHz CPU which may boost %10-20 if all cores are used at the same time.

The CPU Model listed on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms#intel_cpu_processors)

- Xeon Gold 6253CL

Marketing guys sell those CPUs as if they invented a new CPU.